# Outlook Web base addin - How to get timezone's setting in Outlook online?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I'm working on an Office web add-in for Outlook web. But I cannot get timezone from  inside web addin using Js client [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7PEV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAGvs.png)

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user's timezone with Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.timeZone and it is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/Office.context.mailbox.userProfile?view=office-js

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. My expected want to get the full information of Timezone ex: (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris. Do you any suggestion for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately, detailed timezone information is not available. You should be able to use the timezone name and derive that information with a 3rd party service, or roll your own code there. If you think this is something that should be implemented in Office.JS please make a suggestion at our Uservoice link: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins